# Dataframe string to Hive table Bigint - How to convert

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Spark: 1.6, Scala, Hive

I have a dataframe DF.printschema

```
root
 |-- rundatetime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- day_cunt: String (nullable = true)
 |-- my_key: integer (nullable = true)
```

DF.show()

```
rundatetime             |day_cunt | my_key
2017-04-21 11:00:06     | 5       |10
2017-04-21 12:10:06     | 15      |1000
```

My Hive table is

```
rundatetime String,
day_cunt    BigInt,
my_key      Int
Stored as Parquet;
```

How can I save dataframe value to Hive table? Please note DF and hive table Datatype are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInt` isn't a [supported data type](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) for `Spark DataFrames`.

You can create an intermediary dataframe by casting your `day_count` to `Long`:

```
val newDF = df.select($"rundatetime", $"day_count".cast("Long"), $"my_key")
```

Casting with `cast("BigInt")` won't throw errors but will in effect just cast to the `Long` data type.